# How to keep the attributes strictly to the properties of a pydantic class

Tags: python, class, oop, pydantic

For example, this is my class:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Config(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
```

And here's a dictionary:

```py
data = {"name": "XYZ", "age": 18, "height": "180cm"}
```

Now because `height` is not a property of the `Config` class, doing

```py
d = Config(**data)
```

should throw an error but it doesn't. How can I make it throw an error if the dictionary isn't exactly what the class wants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
from pydantic import Extra


class Config(BaseModel, extra=Extra.forbid):
    ...
```

The default is `Extra.ignore`.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/